# Baking path animation deletes poses?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Ok, total edit:

I found out that I have to bake the entire length of the animation to keep all of my keyframes. BUT, now that I've done that, now all of my poses are deleted. The movement stays there, but my character is just in the T-Pose throughout the whole animation. Any help?

[image]

Comment: I downloaded your file and still I don't understand your question, which is the character in the T-Pose throughout the whole animation? Maybe you were in edit mode (if so switch to pose mode and run the animation).

Comment: @joshsanfelici Im trying to say that when I bake action to convert the path movement to keyframes, the rest of the posing that I had done earlier in the animation (the door being kicked open, him walking into the room) is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I basically messed around with it until I figured out that selecting the 'Pose' option in the bake settings only works if you have a bone selected in pose mode, so I just selected all my bones in pose mode, chose 'Pose' and 'Object' in the bake settings, deleted the path, and now it works. Thanks to @joshsanfelici for giving me the idea to check edit mode, which made me think of selecting the bones.